# pandas isin() method returning rows with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I have a dataframe `df_data` and a list `l_ids`. Here's how `df_data.head()` looks like following:

[image]

And `l_lids[:5]` is `[224960004, 60032008, 26677001, 162213003, 72405004]`

I want to get rows that have `l_id` present in list `l_ids`.

So I do this: `df_temp = df_data[df_data.isin(l_ids)]`

However, `df_temp` has rows with *NaN* in it. In fact, `text` field of all rows are *NaN*. Here's what `df_temp.head()` looks like:

[image]

**Cross-check:**

```
print(79823003 in l_ids, 224960004 in l_ids)
True, True
```

As we can `l_ids[0]` is `224960004` which is present in `df_temp` but it's now a `float` and the corresponding `text` is *NaN*. Same with `79823003` and other ids.

Why is this happening? I had gotten the same error in the past also, but I got rows via some other ways and ignored the error. But now that it has happened again in an unrelated project, I feel like am doing some kind of mistake here.

**Extra info**

`df_data.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3577942 entries, 0 to 6953898
Data columns (total 2 columns):
text       object
l_id    int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
```

`df_temp.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3577942 entries, 0 to 6953898
Data columns (total 2 columns):
text       object
l_id    float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

Thus datatype for `l_id` field changed from `int64` to `float64`.

Comment: can you provide sample dataframe?

Comment: Also, what's "l_ids" ? Please include that in the question as well.

Comment: I have updated the question to include head for `df_data` and sample for `l_ids`. Also added a cross-check for two `l_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You statement should be like this:

```
df_temp = df_data[df_data['l_id'].isin(l_ids)]
```

This will check for each row if the value of the column `l_id` is present in the list `l_ids` and return the corresponding rows for which the condition is true. Your mistake was to call `isin()` on the whole dataframe `df_data` instead of just the column `df_data['l_id']`.

Comment: Well this a facepalm moment for me..:( Still can you explain why it is the result that I am getting? Is `isin()` doing a string matching on every field to get me the matching `l_id` in each row?

Comment: Based on the passed values, `df_data[...]` will select whole rows, whole columns or specific entries. Since `df_data['l_id'].isin(l_ids)` returns a `Series` of true/false values, you end up getting the whole rows where the condition is met. `df_data.isin(l_ids)` on the other hand returns a `DataFrame` of true/false values indicating which specific entries to return. Since only the entries in the `l_id` column can actually be in `l_ids` and fulfill the condition, all other entries end up as `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
    'l_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
})

ids = [2, 3]

df[df.apply(lambda x: x['l_id'] in ids, axis=1)]
```